# PHPUnit: How do you Unit test for multiple if-else/factory?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, tdd

I have a class `ParentIdResolver` which returns the parent id of the product based on the type.
The class looks like:

```
<?php

namespace App\Model;

use App\Model\Product\Bundle;
use App\Model\Product\Configurable;
use App\Model\Product\Downloadable;

class ParentIdResolver
{
    /**
     * @var Bundle
     */
    private $bundle;
    /**
     * @var Configurable
     */
    private $configurable;
    /**
     * @var Downloadable
     */
    private $downloadable;

    public function __construct(
        Bundle $bundle,
        Configurable $configurable,
        Downloadable $downloadable
    ) {
        $this->bundle = $bundle;
        $this->configurable = $configurable;
        $this->downloadable = $downloadable;
    }

    public function getParentId($productId, $productType)
    {
        $parentIds = [];
        if ($productType == 'bundle') {
            $parentIds = $this->bundle->getParentIdsByChild($productId);
        } elseif ($productType == 'configurable') {
            $parentIds = $this->configurable->getParentIdsByChild($productId);
        } elseif ($productType == 'downloadable') {
            $parentIds = $this->downloadable->getParentIdsByChild($productId);
        }
        return $parentIds[0] ?? null;
    }
}
```

And I am trying to test the `getParentId()` as:

```
<?php

namespace App\Test\Unit;

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
use App\Model\ParentIdResolver;
use App\Model\Product\Bundle;
use App\Model\Product\Configurable;
use App\Model\Product\Downloadable;

class ParentIdResolverTest extends TestCase
{
    protected $model;
    protected $bundleMock;
    protected $configurableMock;
    protected $downloadableMock;

    public function setUp(): void
    {
        $this->bundleMock = $this->createPartialMock(
            Bundle::class,
            ['getParentIdsByChild']
        );
        $this->configurableMock = $this->createPartialMock(
            Configurable::class,
            ['getParentIdsByChild']
        );
        $this->downloadableMock = $this->createPartialMock(
            Downloadable::class,
            ['getParentIdsByChild']
        );

        $this->model = new ParentIdResolver(
            $this->bundleMock,
            $this->configurableMock,
            $this->downloadableMock
        );
    }

    /**
     * @dataProvider getParentIdDataProvider
     */
    public function testGetParentId($productId, $productType, $parentId)
    {
        if ($productType == 'bundle') {
            $this->bundleMock->expects($this->any())
                ->method('getParentIdsByChild')
                ->willReturn([$parentId]);
        }
        if ($productType == 'configurable') {
            $this->configurableMock->expects($this->any())
                ->method('getParentIdsByChild')
                ->willReturn([$parentId]);
        }
        if ($productType == 'downloadable') {
            $this->downloadableMock->expects($this->any())
                ->method('getParentIdsByChild')
                ->willReturn([$parentId]);
        }

        $this->assertEquals($parentId, $this->model->getParentId($productId, $productType));
    }

    public function getParentIdDataProvider()
    {
        return [
            [1, 'bundle', 11],
            [2, 'configurable', 22],
            [3, 'downloadable', 33],
        ];
    }
}
```

And I don't feel that I am doing it correctly, maybe I need to refactor the main class?
Please suggest how would you refactor or write unit test in this case.

Comment: If the tests are successful and the code works, this would be a better candidate for [Code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @El_Vanja Well noted!

Comment: You could remove all `if` statements from the test and mock for every case at once. The test will be more concise that way

Comment: @PtrTon Yeah, that's another option to refactor the Unit test. But about refactoring the main class? Do you see any room for improvement?

Comment: I've left a more detailed approach for you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66499379/7528944)

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would consider moving the responsibility for resolving the right class towards each class itself. Some would call this "ask, don't tell". It'll look something like this

```
<?php

namespace App\Model;

use App\Model\Product\ResolvesParentId;

class ParentIdResolver
{
    /** @var ResolvesParentId[] */
    private $parentIdResolvers;

    public function __construct(array $parentIdResolvers)
    {
        $this->parentIdResolvers = $parentIdResolvers;
    }

    public function getParentId(int $productId, string $productType): int
    {
        foreach ($this->parentIdResolvers as $parentIdResolver) {
            if ($parentIdResolver->supports($productType)) {
                return $parentIdResolver->getParentId($productId)[0] ?? null;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Model\Product;

interface ResolvesParentId
{
    public function supports(string $productType): bool;

    public function getParentIdsByChild(int $productId): array;
}
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Model\Product;

class Bundle implements ResolvesParentId
{
    public function supports(string $productType): bool
    {
        return $productType === 'bundle';
    }

    public function getParentIdsByChild(int $productId): array
    {
        // Your implementation here.
    }
}
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Model\Product;

class Configurable implements ResolvesParentId
{
    public function supports(string $productType): bool
    {
        return $productType === 'configurable';
    }

    public function getParentIdsByChild(int $productId): array
    {
        // Your implementation here.
    }
}
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Model\Product;

class Downloadable implements ResolvesParentId
{
    public function supports(string $productType): bool
    {
        return $productType === 'downloadable';
    }

    public function getParentIdsByChild(int $productId): array
    {
        // Your implementation here.
    }
}
```

Some consider this overkill, which depends purely on the situation you're in. Do you expect the if/else to grow in the future? Then this solution might be for you.

Comment: You mean "Tell, don't ask" TDA approach?

Comment: Now I feel silly having it wrong all this time :)

Comment: How would you use it? #usage?

Comment: You'd inject an array of containing instances of `Bundle`, `Configurable` and `Downloadable`  into `ParentIdResolver`. Which will then look for the right implementation in that array and resolve the parent id based on it